# How to make a JAR from simplegraph with underlying sources from tinkerpop/gremlin

Tags: java, jar, gremlin, tinkerpop, simplegraph

I have made a JAR from SimpleGraph which I want to use it in a separat project.
In my own project I can see and use the direct classes of SimpleGraph like ExcelSystem etc. but can not use the underlying classes as Vertex etc. from Tinkerpop/Gremlin.
Is there a way to include these into the JAR generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation instructions at http://www.bitplan.com/index.php/SimpleGraph-Installation have been updated according to your question.

To include simplegraph as a single jar dependency for your project you might want to run:

```
cd com.bitplan.simplegraph/simplegraph-bundle
mvn install -D skipTests -D gpg.skip -P createAssembly
```

which will create a jar-with-dependencies.jar